# determining the beginning of a day with timezones AND daylight saving

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm storing the user's timezone as a decimal in the session. For instance, if the user is in the EST timezone, I'd have

```
UserTimeZone = -5.00;
```

The data in the database is stored in UTC, so I want to calculate the beginning and the end of the day for that user so that when the user wants his data for a specific day, the records are timezone adjusted.

This is what I'm doing:

```
DateTime StartDate =  DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

StartDate = StartDate.AddHours((double)UserTimeZone);
StartDate = StartDate.Date;
StartDate = StartDate.AddHours((double)UserTimeZone);

DateTime EndDate = StartDate.AddHours(24);
```

The problem I'm having is that this doesn't account for daylight saving time so even thought EST time is 5 hours behind UTC, for the moment it's actually 4 hours behind UTC because of the daylight saving shift.

What are some of your suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I don' think just having a time offset is enough, look into `TimeZone` / `TimeZoneInfo`

Comment: Don't use DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(), use DateTime.UtcNow

Comment: Not all time zones are integer offsets, so even when you switch to getting the offset from the browser you'll need to use something better than an int.

Comment: I'm not using an int, I'm using a decimal. I checked and I didn't find any difference between ToUniversalTime() and DateTime.UtcNow, even when changing the computer's date to some time in December.

Comment: using a Decimal is good but not enough... are you storing only this offset per User ? that is not enough - you need to store whether this offset includes daylight saving or not... with both (offset and whether offset includes DS) one can build a working algorithm (although not 100% consistent - best is to store a real Timezone per User!), otherwise NOT :-(

Comment: Yes, at the moment, I'm only storing the timezone offset. If the user tells me he's in the EST timezone, is there a good way to know if he's at UTC-5 or UTC-4 without knowing anything else?

Comment: Hi! I was glad to be of help. Please consider awarding the bounty if the accepted answer is satisfactory, since the system will let it expire.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make such calculations you will need to use the `TimeZoneInfo` and `DateTimeOffset` classes.

First of all, we need to get a `TimeZoneInfo` instance for both the local time and the user's local time:

```
var localTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
var userTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
```

The caveat here is that you need to know the id of the user's local timezone (the offset that you currently have is not going to be enough). You can get a list of all `TimeZoneInfo` instances that the system recognizes with [`TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx), and then you need a way of matching the user-provided timezone with one of those.

For this example, I have hardcoded EST.

Then you need to get a `DateTimeOffset` instance for today's midnight (start of day) in your local timezone:

```
var todayDate = DateTime.Today;
var todayLocal = new DateTimeOffset(todayDate,
                                    localTimezone.GetUtcOffset(todayDate));
```

Given this, you can calculate the `DateTimeOffset` instance that represents the midnight of "today" (based on your local time) in the user's timezone. **Be aware that, depending on timezones, this may actually be in the future for the user's timezone!**

```
var todayUser = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(todayLocal, userTimezone);
```

And finally, you can create timestamps for both dates like this:

```
var epochStart = DateTime.Parse("01/01/1970 00:00:00");
var todayLocalTs = (todayLocal.Ticks - epochStart.Ticks)/TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
var todayUserTs = (todayUser.Ticks - epochStart.Ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
```

Comment: Also, avoid using "EST", it and other TZ abbreviations are not globally unique :( Either use the UTC offset, or use the full timezone name ("Ameria/NewYork"). More info in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309030/difference-between-timezones-america-los-angeles-and-us-pacific-and-pst8pdt

Comment: @jpeacock: .NET is picky with its timezone names however (you do need to see them with `GetSystemTimeZones`). Also, you cannot use the UTC offset -- that's what the OP is doing right now, and it's not satisfactory.

Comment: @frenchie: Original Poster -- you. :)

Answer (score 3):

As BrokenGlass mentioned, a simple offset is not enough information to determine the handling of daylight hours, since different countries in each zone might handle daylight savings differently.  The C# `TimeZone` class is more specific, and has support for daylight savings (check details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.aspx)).  Unfortunately there is no easy way to get the relevant timezone from the browser, but there are several suggestions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832986/how-to-work-with-timezone-in-asp-net) regarding how you can allow the user to pick their timezone.

If you want to try and work out the timezone without the user's assistance, there are a few ways to do that (typically revolving around getting the browser's preferred language, and then mapping that to a country...), some examples are [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1091541/1637555.aspx) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/772971a4-9f1b-4004-a873-c1e0e2098852/).

Comment: The user provides his timezone at the time of registration; what i need is a way to determine if his timezone is under daylight saving.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) - bottom line, your definition of timezone information is not sufficient to determine daylight savings.  You want them to provide you with their *country*, as well as their time zone within that country.

Comment: Daniel is correct, especially since a time zone spans from north to south, yet daylight saving times in the north and south hemisphere are at exactly opposite times.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use JavaScript to gather the necessary information from the user's browser - for this part see http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/

When you have this information you can setup `UserTimeZone` (btw this should NOT be an `int` as there are timezones with fractions of hours!) to accomodate the current timezone including DST...

Comment: The user provides his timezone at the time of registration; what i need is a way to determine if his timezone is under daylight saving.

Comment: If you follow the link it provides a way to find out whether the current timezone of the user is under daylight saving!

Comment: Javascript is not the way I'm looking to do it. The user provides me with his timezone (and address too) at registration time and I need to figure out the time at which his day starts with consideration to the daylight saving time. He could be from California and travelling to the East Coast, with a browser showing EST at an internet cafe.

Comment: whether this is possible depends absolutely on what the user provides as "timezone information" - if you show that (code, data, whatever "timezone information" you store with the user) then it is at least possible to try to find a way...

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer doesn't consider that there are time zones that have DST spring-forward transitions right at midnight, and thus the start of the day might not be `00:00` but rather `01:00`.  Iran, Cuba, and Brazil (some parts) are good examples.

Additionally, some time zones may have fall-back transitions that give two possible point in time that are midnight.

Consider the following function, which accommodates both scenarios:

```
using System.Linq;

static DateTimeOffset GetStartOfDay(DateTime dt, TimeZoneInfo tz)
{
    // Work in the time zone provided
    if (dt.Kind != DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
    {
        dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dt, tz);
    }

    // Start with assuming midnight
    var d = dt.Date;

    // Check for the time being invalid and handle if so
    if (tz.IsInvalidTime(d))
    {
        // the gap is *usually* 1hr, but not always, so calculate it
        var gap = tz.GetUtcOffset(dt.AddDays(1)) - tz.GetUtcOffset(dt.AddDays(-1));

        // advance forward by the amount of the gap
        d = d.Add(gap);
    }

    // Also check for the time being ambiguous, such as in a fall-back transition.
    // We want the *first* occurrence, which will have a *larger* offset
    var offset = tz.IsAmbiguousTime(d)
        ? tz.GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets(d).OrderByDescending(x => x).First()
        : tz.GetUtcOffset(d);

    // Now we know when the date starts precisely
    return new DateTimeOffset(d, offset);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. An example of the ambiguous case is that of Cuba, where they put the clocks back from 01:00 to 00:00 in Autumn: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/cuba/havana?year=2018

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is what everyone has told you to do - use the TimeZone APIs in the framework.  But prior to .NET 3.5 the TimeZoneInfo APIs didnt exist.  If you really don't want to use the APIS, or you are using something prior to .NET 3.5, you can find all the timezone info in the registry at

`HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/Timezones`

There are a set of classes available at http://www.michaelbrumm.com/simpletimezone.html that read the registry data directly and do all the timezone calculations required - with adjustments for DST.  It's good code (we've used it reliably for years) with source, so you can see what they are actually doing.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend adding a timezone to the users settings and storing that. Timezones have different times depending on the time of year. you can provide a list of time zones for the user to choose from by using the [TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx) method. You can store any date as UTC and convert it (with the [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770.aspx) method) to the users time when displaying, and convert it back to UTC when saving it. This will allow the user to change their timezone at any time without causing problems. If you follow this format you should not run into any problems.

Be forewarned, if you do not store the dates as UTC and convert as suggested above you may run into problems. In some time zones certain times do not exist on certain days when changing from daylight savings time to standard time. The TimeZoneInfo class does not play nice with these non-existent times.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing any of this.  You should just use the TimeZoneInfo built into .net.

For example:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc();
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc();
```

Since you don't seem able to lookup API Parameters, here you go:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb381744.aspx

Comment: And where do I pass the timezone info. I'm looking to get the user's beginning-of-day time (StartTime) so that I can put that time in my queries. I'm looking for something like StartTime = function GetStartTime(Date, UserTimeZone).

Comment: @frenchie - pardon me for assuming you would actually look at the API reference to see the arguments to pass to it.  So silly of me to think you would do that.

Comment: right, so the problem is not in converting time zones to UTC and back, the problem is that if given a timezone offset (ie -5.00 for EST), how do I know if the EST timezone is -5 hours from UTC or -4 hours from UTC in case of day light saving time. The goal is to determine the UTC time of the start of the user's day. Some days it'll be UTC -5 and others it'll be UTC-4, depending on the daylight saving time. If the user wants to see data for HIS september 18th, I need to know what the start time is in UTC format AND taking daylight saving time into consideration.

Comment: @frenchie - That's the point.  You don't have to if you use the TimeZoneInfo functions.  It figures that out for you.  You just have to pass it the right TimeZoneInfo, which you save in your users profile when they register.  Forget about offsets, they are unimportant.

Comment: Where do I find the list of all timezones supported by this class? This page gives a list by OS but how do I find the list based on the server's OS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384272.aspx

Comment: @frenchie - it supports all time zones supported by the OS.  This is a user definable thing (although most users won't be bothered to create custom time zones).  If you would read the documentation, you would see a method called `GetSystemTimeZones()` which returns an enumeration of all time zones on the system.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need time-zone file http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm
`Record all you time in UTC/GMT.`

Day Light saving is not consistent, countries change their DLS rule.
Hence your application will need up-to-date Tz file at all the time.

Your user should choose `Time-Zone name` when signing up and not time-offset. Because two regions can have same time offset (sometimes with DLS).

With `Tz Name` you can know
- what **country/region** user belongs to;
- what is `his time offset`;
- and what is `his DLS offset`,
`add these both` to get users current time.

Known Issue: Time in history cannot be converted to actual time if you don't have historic DLS details, as these may not be valid at that historic time.

Comment: Your server will have this file up-to-date already; and your APIs will give DLS adjusted time if you pass on Tz name instead of time-offset.