# Is it possible to create a cron schedule based on PDT without timezone specified? say, timezone is tied to UTC

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, timezone, amazon-cloudwatch

**Goal**: Create a consistent cron expression that fires every Sunday at midnight in PDT. without changing the expression twice a year.

**Limitation**: Can't specify timezone. all expressions are based on UTC

**Background**: AWS CloudWatch event supports cron expression but it defaults to UTC.

I believe it is easy in `UTC` to `PST`

```
0 8 * ? SUN *
```

But, what if I need it to be `PDT`?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature of the job, here's a potential hack:

```
0 7,8 * ? SUN *
```

This only works if the triggered job is something that has enough internal logic capability that it can decide for itself whether or not it should continue execution.

When the job starts, it must have an internal way of checking the current time after conversion from system time to `America/Los_Angeles` (or [whatever](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4309030/1695906) it might be called in whatever time zone library is available at runtime), to determine whether the current time in that time zone is near enough to midnight -- in which case it should proceed as normal -- or if the current time is closer to +/- ~1 hour from midnight, in which case it should just terminate quietly without doing any work.  The job spawns twice on each appointed day, but one of the two invocations quickly finishes so few resources are used.